# How to write xpath when the button is disabled : Selenium + java + salesforce

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to click on button only if it is enabled, if the button is disabled   i would not click on the button and proceed further.

When i write the Xpath and check if the webElement is Enabled, resulting in Enabled always and i dont see much difference in html as well to differential between enabled and disabled.

Help me with writing the xpath which should work only when the element is Enabled.

I have tried to below xpath :
//button[NOT(@disable) and span[text()='More Steps']]

Above xpath is not working.

When the element is Enabled :

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral showMoreButton uiButton" aria-live="off" type="button" data-aura-rendered-by="2703:0" data-aura-class="uiButton"><!--render facet: 2704:0--><span class=" label bBody" dir="ltr" data-aura-rendered-by="2706:0">More Steps</span><!--render facet: 2708:0--></button>

<span class=" label bBody" dir="ltr" data-aura-rendered-by="2706:0">More Steps</span>
```

When the element is Disabled :

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral showMoreButton uiButton" aria-live="off" type="button" disabled data-aura-rendered-by="2703:0" data-aura-class="uiButton"><!--render facet: 2704:0--><span class=" label bBody" dir="ltr" data-aura-rendered-by="2706:0">More Steps</span><!--render facet: 2708:0--></button>

<span class=" label bBody" dir="ltr" data-aura-rendered-by="2706:0">More Steps</span>
```

Actual : When the element is not disabled, User is able to click on that but when it is disabled still user is trying to click that

Expected : User should be able to click on the element only when it is Enabled

Note : Do not mark the question as duplicate, this is with respect to salesforce tags, please understand.

THanks in advance for your suggestions/Solutions

Comment: Wierd: driver.findElement(VALID LOCATOR).getAttribute("NONEXISTING ATTRIBUTE"); throws no exception.

Answer (score 1):

When the button is disabled - xpath

```
//div[span/text()='More Steps']
```

returns two elements. One of them is in the part of the DOM that is not displayed.

[check out the DOM tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cscRN.png)

This longer xpath will work as you need because it looks inside active pane only

```
//div[contains(@class,'active')]//button[not(@disabled) and span/text()='More Steps']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public boolean elementIsEnabled = new Boolean(false);

public boolean elementIsEnabled() {
    if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(@data-aura-rendered-by,'2703:0')]")).size() == 1) {
        elementIsEnabled = true;
    }
    else if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(@disabled data-aura-rendered-by,'2703:0')]")).size() == 1) {
        elementIsEnabled = false;
    }
    return elementIsEnabled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**"Try out below code-**

if(Globals.driver.findElement(By.xpath(""//button[text()='your text']"")).getAttribute(""attribute"").equals(""false"")){
        Globals.driver.findElement(By.className(""your button class"")).findElement(By.xpath(""//button[text()='your text']"")).click();
      }
else{
    Globals.driver.findElement(By.className(""your button class"")).findElement(By.xpath(""//button[text()='your text']"")).click();

}"